# Firefox addon to imitate Google Chrome's built-in notification system

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, notifications, firefox

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 4 and I would like to be able to receive notifications similar to Google Chrome's built-in notification system, like so:

[image]

Is there an addon like this or similar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-notifications/?src=collection&collection_id=5a09670e-9ad4-45e9-9f80-70b37296dd83) appears to do the job - its experimental, so it might either stop working in future, or rolled into mainline firefox in future.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can try the [Tab Notifier Extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/tab-notifier/).

It provides desktop notifications really similar to Chrome’s ones (e.g. more windows are piled up vertically), as you can see in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RURYLevwRo).

[image: Tab notifier Screenshot on Windows]

It appears you are using Mac OS X, and so you should note that this extension needs Growl to work on Mac, that it's not supported by the last versions.

---

This extension other than supporting website coded for Chrome-like Desktop Notifications (eg: GMail is supported) also optionally enables to receive notifications virtually for any website by watching for changes to its title.

---

*Disclosure: the original author of this Answer is the Extension coder*

Answer (score 1):

Extension to add desktop notifications into firefox, the way it works with Chrome and Chromium Browser : works with gmail, gtalk (gmail chat), imo.im, and all other websites that use this technology.

[HTML Desktop Notifications](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-notifications/?src=collection&collection_id=5a09670e-9ad4-45e9-9f80-70b37296dd83)